# Illegal assignment from List<WorkOrder> to List<WorkOrder>

Tags: work-order

Trying to run this very simple operation and getting exception as in title:

```
list<workorder> o = [select id from workorder];
```

Wat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally this type of error occur when there are 2 different type of class has the same same. so the Name is same but signature is different.
I am from salesforce apex so I can suggest you to check for your metadata whether there are any 2 same name class/settings/object exist in your system.

Comment: WorkOrder is a standard object and @dzh might be having a class with same name (as you have mentioned). But two classes cannot have same name. In such cases, system gets confused and uses the defined class.

Comment: He might created a Wrapper class with name 'WorkOrder' ?
This often happens.

Comment: Ah yes must be it. Hits me twice this month - someone created class `test` recently and out of the sudden all tests started failing. Lol!

Comment: For all the System classes, you can maybe append 'System.' to avoid such issues. like. System.Trigger.new instead of Trigger.new